# Python scripting langue cannot be executed automate

Tags: python

I followed the instruction from internet to make a scripting for automating boring stuff in my computer.

I have some bugs when executing,

Could anyone show me what is the issue ? and suggestion for this case.
code :

```
# import python libraries

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import os
import shutil


def file_organizer(mypath):
    '''
    A function to sort the files in a download folder
    into their respective categories
    '''
    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    file_type_variation_list = []
    filetype_folder_dict = {}
    for file in files:
        filenamebrake = file.split('.')
        filetype = filenamebrake[len(filenamebrake) - 1]
        if filetype not in file_type_variation_list:
            file_type_variation_list.append(filetype)
            new_folder_name = mypath + '/' + filetype + '_folder'
            filetype_folder_dict[str(filetype)] = str(new_folder_name)
            if os.path.isdir(new_folder_name) == True:  # folder exists
                continue
            else:
                os.mkdir(new_folder_name)
    for file in files:
        src_path = mypath + '/' + file
        filenamebrake = file.split('.')
        filetype = filenamebrake[len(filenamebrake) - 1]
        if filetype in filetype_folder_dict.keys():
            dest_path = filetype_folder_dict[str(filetype)]
            shutil.move(src_path, dest_path)
    print("File Organization Completed " + str(mypath))
    mypath = 'C:/Users/snguyend/Downloads'


mypath = str(input("Enter Path "))
file_organizer(mypath)
```

Error message when executing the cmd

```
C:\Users\snguyend\Desktop\Python Anaconda>python organizebot.py
Enter Path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "organizebot.py", line 40, in <module>
    file_organizer(mypath)
  File "organizebot.py", line 14, in file_organizer
    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

C:\Users\snguyend\Desktop\Python Anaconda>
```

[Link to code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DS8V9JyhajdrMmhr9Q3df4ticKYrrZ2g/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: did you type `C:/Users/snguyend/Downloads` when the terminal had `Enter Path` ? if you want it hard coded you can just replace `mypath = str(input("Enter Path "))` with `mypath = 'C:/Users/snguyend/Downloads'`

Comment: Are you not supposed to enter a path from the console input, when you see 'Enter Path' at the prompt? From your terminal output, it appears you didn't do so.

Comment: are you running cmd as Administrator or are you administrator in your computer?

Comment: Thanks all for your quickly responding.@ Mohnish: It worked with your suggestion. Thank you so much bro :)

Comment: @Nikil , when executing the code in the terminal " Enter Path " appears , then click enter button , error message pop up in the prompt. might something wrong the path setting in the code.. Thank you so much